# Adding a method through the prototype

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a height method but now when i call it without the `()`.
How can i use this it as a method  the `benji.height()` method?I mean with the Parenthesis at the end?

```
function Dog() {
    this.tail = true;
    this.height = 33;

}
 var benji = new Dog();
 var rusty = new Dog();

 Dog.prototype.height = function() {
     return "the height is " +  this.height + " cms";
 };

console.log(benji.height);
```

Comment: @Tushar the code is in front of you. i am asking that why can not i call the height method using benji.height().. Instead i just use benji.height..?

Comment: Because you have a field `height`. Give unambiguous names to your fields and methods.

Comment: Why not rename the method? [Like `getHeight`](http://jsfiddle.net/o6pdvkn1/)? Much more meaningful. The easiest way to think about this is that methods are actions not nouns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a field named `height` and you are trying to add a method called `height`.
You need to give it an unambigious name and it will work.

```js
function Dog() {
    this.tail = true;
    this.height = 33;

}
 var benji = new Dog();
 var rusty = new Dog();

 Dog.prototype.getHeight = function() {
     return "the height is " +  this.height + " cms";
 };

document.body.innerHTML = "<b>height:</b> " + (benji.height) + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += "<b>getHeight():</b> " + benji.getHeight();
```

Comment: yes but in console or in pure Js can i use getHeight()?

Answer (score 1):

So you have height variable in both the place Object and object prototype. So according to prototype chain it will first lookup in Object and then its prototype.

Here

```
function Dog() {
    this.tail = true;
    this.height = 33;

}
```

height variable will store in object So it will find height which is not a function that a reason you are not able to call as `benji.height();`

So as other user suggest just change the name of function you can call it as you want.